# Access Class method and variable using self

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, class-method, class-variables

In below example **Test** class has two instance method and one classmethod

In **set_cls_var_1** method I set class variable using self.

In **set_cls_var_2** method I call class method using self.

```
   class Test():

        #class variable
        cls_var = 10

        def __init__(self):
           obj_var=20

        def set_cls_var_1(self,val):
            #second method to access class variable
            print "first "
            self.cls_var = val

        def set_cls_var_2(self):
            print "second"
            self.task(200)

        @classmethod
        def task(cls,val):
            cls.cls_var = val


t=Test()

#set class variable by first method
t.set_cls_var_1(100)

print Test.cls_var

#set class variable by second method
t.set_cls_var_2()

print Test.cls_var
```

**Output**

```
first 
10
second
200
```

**Expected Output**

```
first 
100
second
200
```

My question is:
   why only classmethod can call by self, Why not class variable

Comment: Assigning attributes on an instance will never assign to a class attribute.

Comment: But when I can access  "cls_var" in "set_cls_var_1" like "print self.cls_var". why and how that possible, I don't understand

Comment: that mean i can only get class variable in instance method ,cant set class variable in instance method using self

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you attempt to access an object's attribute using `self`, Python first searches the object's attributes. If it cannot find it there, then is searches the object's class's attributes. That is what's happening in your case;

Python first searches `t`'s attributes. It doesn't find `cls_var`, so it then searches the `T` class's attributes. It finds `cls_var` so it stops, and returns `cls_var`'s value.

However, when assigning attributes to `self`, Python always assigns them directly to the object, and never the object's class unless explicitly told to do so. That's why assinging `self.cls_var` to `100` didn't affect `Test`'s `cls_var` attrbiute.

Comment: then why error when try to print cls.obj_var in class method if  Python first searches the object's attributes. If it cannot find it there, then it searches the object's class's attributes.

Comment: @Kallz Because `obj_var` belongs to the _**object**_, not the _**class**_. Python raised an error because `T` does not have a `obj_var`, only the object's of `T` do.

Answer (score 8):

I find something else that always use following way to access classmethod or variable in instance method

```
class Test():
    #class variable
    cls_var = 10

    def __init__(self):
        obj_var=20

    def set_cls_var_1(self,val):
        #first method to access class variable
        print "first type"
        cls = self.__class__
        cls.cls_var = val



t=Test()
#set class variable by first method

t.set_cls_var_1(100)

print Test.cls_var
```

Answer (score 2):

When defining the Test class like you did, python creates a class object called Test which has an attribute `cls_var` equal to 10. When you instantiate this class, the created object doesn't have `cls_var` attribute. When calling `self.cls_var` it is actually the class' attribute that is retrieved due to the way python resolves attributes.

However when set `self.cls_var` the value is set at the object level! So further call to `self.cls_var` will give you the value of the object's attribute, and not the class' anymore!

Maybe this bit of code will make this clearer:

```
class A(object):
    a = 1
a = A()
print a.a  # prints 1
A.a = 2
print a.a  # prints 2
```

You see that even though when set the value at the class level, the changes are repercuted on the object, because, python will look up for the attribute in the class when it is not found at the object level.

When calling `Test.cls_var` it is the `cls_var` attribute of the class you are accessing! Not the one of the object you just modified.